# Command to Change version of R RStudio is running Mac Mojave

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

I have two versions of R installed and I want to change the 'current version'.  Navigating to the directory, I see the following:

```
192 Jul 18 07:48 3.3
256 Jul 19 15:12 3.6
3 Jul 18 07:48 Current -> 3.3
```

What is the command I need to use to have version 3.6 be current?

Comment: Just for RStudio right? Not under another IDE, environment or package manager? Do you mean under RStudio? Conda/Anaconda? Virtualbox? something else? UNIX path?

Comment: Hi yes, using RStudio